# What Happens If I Run My Advanced Pump Continuously?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

What happens if the Advanced Pump is left running continuously and the output pipe is full? I noticed it will continue to consume power, but does it stop pumping until there is enough room in the pipe to take more liquid, or does the excess get wasted?

Comment: I think it stops pumping, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

It's just like you said, it stops pumping until there is enough room in the pipe to take in more liquid.